# How to uninstall iTerm form the mac?

Tags: macos, terminal, terminal.app, iterm2, iterm

How can I uninstall iTerm from my Mac? I searched a lot on the Internet but I didn't find any helpful Informations.
I want to mention too that I installed iTerm without using Homebrew.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32483710/how-to-uninstall-iterm2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide more information on your issue. As [Tetsujin](https://superuser.com/users/347380/tetsujin) linked, you can simply go to `/Applications` and move the `iTerm` app to the trash (see [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32483710/how-to-uninstall-iterm2)). This is how you uninstall all macOS applications (unless you are using Homebrew). Any internet search can show you this step by step.

Now, I am guessing that you want to also uninstall all the hidden files that `iTerm` creates on your computer. I would recommend taking a look at this [tread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8483999) which shows some other hidden file locations:

```
    caches files in ~Library/Caches
    preferences files in ~Library/Preferences
    log files in ~Library/Logs
    Other files in
        ~Library/Containers
        ~Library/Cookies
        ~Library/Address Book Plug-Ins
        ~Library/Saved Application State
        ~private/var/db/BootCaches
```

You could manually delete iTerm's folders within these one at a time. Just be sure not to accidentally delete anything important to another application.

Now, you mentioned that you didn't install using Homebrew. I think you can still uninstall an application with Homebrew even if you didn't use Homebrew to install it. Usually using Brew you could just run:

```
brew uninstall --force iterm
```

You can add `--zap` to get rid of hidden files in the `~/Library` folder:

```
brew uninstall --force --zap iterm
```

If you don't have Homebrew, you can always go to the [website](https://brew.sh/). Search `iTerm` and select [`cask code`](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/blob/HEAD/Casks/iterm2.rb). Then delete the files under zap trash from your computer after you've moved the iTerm application to the trash.

```
zap trash: [
    "~/Library/Application Support/iTerm",
    "~/Library/Application Support/iTerm2",
    "~/Library/Application Support/com.apple.sharedfilelist/com.apple.LSSharedFileList.ApplicationRecentDocuments/com.googlecode.iterm2.sfl*",
    "~/Library/Caches/com.googlecode.iterm2",
    "~/Library/Cookies/com.googlecode.iterm2.binarycookies",
    "~/Library/Preferences/com.googlecode.iterm2.plist",
    "~/Library/Saved Application State/com.googlecode.iterm2.savedState",
  ]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!